# search query for many dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, search, get

My databse is:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(77) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(77) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
  `level` varchar(33) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1, 'majid', '123', '2012-04-16', 'admin');
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (2, 'feras', '123', '2012-04-15', 'gs');
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (3, 'sami', '123', '2012-04-12', 'gs');
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (4, 'rashed', '123', '2012-04-09', 'gs');
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (5, 'saad', 'dfd', '2012-04-13', 'bb');
```

My search page is a form with three dropdown lists... first for name, second for pass and third for level.

Now, if I choose one drop list it will gives me a good result, but if I choose two or more lists it does not give me anything.

How can I make all that dropdown lists act like a filter for a specific result?
Like "all pass (123) and level (gs)"

My query is:

```
$name= $_GET['name'];
$pass= $_GET['pass'];
$level= $_GET['level'];
mysql_select_db($database_sqltest, $sqltest);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE '$name' OR pass LIKE '$pass' OR level LIKE '$level'";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $sqltest) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
```

Comment: On a side note: mysql functions are deprecated now. Move over to mysqli or PDO. Furthermore, your query is vulnerale to SQL injection and you should really be hashing the password (with a salt preferably) and not storing it as plain text.

Comment: You're taking user input directly from $_GET and putting it into a MySQL query - this is very dangerous.  See http://bobby-tables.com/ for why.

Comment: @Flukey, you are not correct, those functions have not been deprecated. `mysql_db_query()` was in 5.3, but not the functions used by OP above.

Comment: @SetSailMedia  Yes it has, just because it's  in PHP 5.3 doesn't mean it's not deprecated. http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799. Furthemore, people should move away from the mysql functions they're awful! Start using parameterised queries! There are many mysql functions which are marked as deprecated in the manual.

Comment: @Flukey Just because someone posted a proposal in the news db forum, does not mean it's officially deprecated. I don't find any deprecation mention in the PHP manual for `mysql_select_db()`, `mysql_query()` nor `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `mysql_num_rows()`. Are we looking at the same manual?

Comment: Here's an example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php. Anyway, people should move away from the mysql functions. Start taking advantage of prepared statements and objects in PDO (or use an ORM on top) mysql queries are long gone and are considered insecure and ugly. Although it's not fully deprecated....I wish it would be and people would move away from procedural programming to object-oriented programming.#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `AND` operator instead of `OR` to increase specificity and limit the query. I've added `%` signs (wildcards) so that a search for "12" would match pass "123". You can remove them if you won't want that functionality.

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE `pass` LIKE '%$pass%' AND `level` LIKE '%$level%' AND `name` LIKE '%$name%'";
```

Comment: but if i use AND i must choose all the dropdown lists ... if i choose one or two it will not give any thing ...

Comment: Did you actually try this before making that assumption? With the % wildcard characters on either side, the behavior you describe is not true. You can choose one or more dropdown lists, but you do NOT need to choose all.